# Supplying a Docker container with a PHP SOAP client

Tags: php, docker, api, soap

The SOAP client is not installed for PHP Docker containers, i want know what is the correct way to use it ?

**Note**: i'm using a *PHP 7.4* image build with *docker-compose* & *Dockefile*

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:** add this line in the Dockerfile :

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
libxml2-dev \

RUN docker-php-ext-install soap
```

**Step 2**: In php.ini, find remove the commenting semicolon at the beginning of the line:

```
extension=php_soap.dll
```

or

```
extension=soap
```

**Step 3**: rebuild the image with this command:

```
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build
```

**Step 4**: With phpinfo() check if Soap Client is enabled :

[image]